# Separation of Variables Viable Here?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Say we have $\frac{dx}{dy}=z-vx$. Could we separate the variables as $\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{z}{x}dy-vdy$? The reason I ask is because a friend of mine believes this is the way to solve this problem, but isn't the whole point of separation of variables to have each variable on one side? In this case we still have a $x$ on the right hand side. This bothers me for some reason.

I think my professor may have made a mistake and wanted to do $\frac{dx}{dy}=(z-v)x$ because in all of our examples for this type of problem she used separation of variables.

Comment: Where did $t$ come from?

Comment: @GrahamKemp Excuse me, it should have been $y$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The object *is* to algebraically rearrange the equality so that all the $x$ are on one side, and all the $y$ are on the other side.

$$\frac{\mathrm d x}{\mathrm d y} = z - vx \implies \frac{\mathrm d x}{z-vx}= \mathrm d y$$

The intention is to arrive at a conveniently solvable integral equality.   In this case we have: $$\begin{align}\int \operatorname d y & = \int \frac 1 {z-vx}\operatorname d x
\\[2ex] y -c & = \frac 1{-v} \int(z-vx)^{-1}\operatorname d(z-vx)
\\[2ex]\therefore y & = c-\frac 1 v\ln (z-vx)
\end{align}$$